# Linearity of a map

Tags: linear-algebra

Confusion about linearity. We say $ax+c$ is linear because it only contains linear terms. But it would not be right to say this is a linear operator/map since $T(Lx) \neq LT(x)$ ?

In this video @5:48: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=442PxdU35q4&list=PLBh2i93oe2qsGKDOsuVVw-OCAfprrnGfr&index=13 the author claims that $Tx_n$ as $x_n$ goes to $0$ is $0$. ($x_n$ is a sequence)

My guess is we are allowed to say $Tx_n$ goes to $0$ as $x_n$ goes to $0$ right because the operator can't have a shift/offset (otherwise it would be non-zero at $x= 0$) and the linearity ensures this?

Therefore an operator with $Tx \neq 0$ at x=0 can't be linear ?

Comment: Note that if $f(x)=ax+c$ and $c \neq 0$ then $f(\alpha x) \neq \alpha f(x)$ so it is not linear.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There are two competing definitions of "linear" in common use. The function $f(x) = ax + c$ fails to be "linear" in the sense of a linear transformation or linear operator because $T(kx) \neq kT(x)$ for scalars $k$. On ther other hand, $f$ is a "linear function" in the sense that it is a function whose graph is a line. We may also characterize $f$ as being an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).